# how to convert negative seconds to hours minutes format in php

Tags: php, time, minute

how to convert negative seconds to hours minutes, I try this

```
$todo_tm = -900;
echo gmdate("H:i", $todo_tm);
```

the output is,

```
23:45
```

my expectation is,

```
-00:15
```

how to achieve this, any suggestion.

Comment: It starts counting at midnight. 900 seconds is 15 minutes. 15 minutes before midnight is 23:45. What, exactly, is the problem? I think you need to rethink your expectations.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: this is sample code, my need is to calculate the time, for two different time and convert to hours and minutes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
$todo_tm = -900;
$time    = gmdate("H:i", abs($todo_tm));

if ($todo_tm < 0) {
    $time = '-' . $time;
}
```

Comment: Your code can be reduced to `echo gmdate("H:i", abs($todo_tm));`

Comment: I've fixed that already.

Comment: I have a feeling that for `$todo_tm = -90000;` OP would expect `-25:00`, not `-1:00`

Comment: In this case we should not use `gmdate` but calculate hours/minutes manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use [abs](https://www.php.net/abs) to convert in absolute value, then use gmdate().

```
$todo_tm = abs(-900);
echo gmdate("H:i", $todo_tm);
// Output : 00:15
```